# How can I grab multiple elements with the same selector using async wdio?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webdriver, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I am using async wdio to test my react app and would like count some elements that have a particular selector as well as check for some things in them. This is what the code I am testing looks like:

```
<div className='container'>
  <li className='my-element'>
    <button>Button 1</button>
  </li>
  <li className='my-element'>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </li>
  <li className='my-element'>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </li>
</div>
```

So basically what I would like to do is count the number of `li` tags with the class `my-element` and check for the contents of each one of them.
Based on the [docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$$.html), it would seem that I want to use `$$` on the `.container`, so something like this:

```js
it('count my-elements', async function () {
  const container = await $('.container')
  const myElements = await $$('.my-element') // gives me some weird array with an element object
  console.log(myElements)
})
```

This is the object I get from the `console.log`:

```
[
  parent: Element {
    sessionId: '12bd5537ee1cee33e1f23d0e1a162a40',
    elementId: '0.345325829273438-8',
    ELEMENT: '0.345325829273438-8',
    selector: '.container',
    parent: Browser {
      sessionId: '12bd5537ee1cee33e1f23d0e1a162a40',
      capabilities: [Object],
      addCommand: [Function],
      overwriteCommand: [Function],
      addLocatorStrategy: [Function],
      config: [Object]
    },
    emit: [Function: bound ],
    isReactElement: false,
    addCommand: [Function],
    overwriteCommand: [Function]
  },
  selector: '.my-element',
  foundWith: '$$',
  props: []
]
```

Not sure what to do with this or how to actually check for all the elements I got with that selector.

So in conclusion, for starters I would like to count how many elements were selected with that particular selector and perhaps be able to go in deeper to each one and see/access their contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ returns an array of elements. To get the number of the elements you need to use the 
[Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

So

`myElements.length` will give you the number of the elements you found with `$$`

__

Not sure what you mean by "see/access their contents". But if you want for instance get the text of the each element you found you can perform any action that is suitable for array (e.g `forEach`)